# How to add a new row to p-table when the table is empty?

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng, p-table

I have a datatable with mock data and multiple rows and an add button in the end to add a new row.
The problem is when there is no data in the table, I mean no rows, the add button doesn't add the initial row?

I took this as a reference: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablecrud-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

My stackblitz code: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdfkfo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**app.component.ts**

```
triggerAdd() {
   
  this.addMode = !this.addMode;
}
onRowAddSave(customer: any) {

  if(Object.keys(customer).length !== 0 ){
 
    this.launchMaturity.push(customer);
    this.formatProduct(this.launchMaturity);
    this.addMode = false;
    this.newAttribute = {};
  }
}
onRowCancelSave() {
  this.addMode = false;
}
}


public formatProduct(value: any) {
  this.formatData = [];
  this.exportable = true;

  value.map((a: any) => this.formatData.push(a));

 }
}

public launchMaturity: any[];
```

Comment: if you could replicate the issue that you are facing in a stackblitz instance and share the link with us, we could help you a lot faster

Comment: @CCBet Hi, I actually shared my stackblitz in here as a link.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice it

Comment: I don't know if for anybody else the solution on stackblitz is building successfully, but in my case it's throwing an error related to the file-saver dependency

Comment: @CCBet You should add 
-primeng/api

-file-saver
to dependencies to the left bottom of the page. Then you should check Enable Ivy option from settings. This should download the project.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).